How to configure HTTP version used by Spring Kafka Consumer
I am having an issue with my Kafka consumer in Kotlin, where, upon message consumption using @KafkaListner, the following error occurs. I am struggling to understand why the error is occurring and where I have to make a change.
It seems like this http2 error means i am sending http1 when http2 is expected like in this thread: GRPC Client - Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f but i am not explictly sending any HTTP request from my side, although perhaps the consumer is communicating through one?
but I couldnt find anywhere in the kafka config where this is specified?
Using Spring-Kafka ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory version 2.8.11 with a version 11 JDK
exception":{"exception_class":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException",
  "exception_message":"Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.path.MyConsumer.consume(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String,
  byte[]>,
  org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment)' threw exception; nested exception is io.grpc.StatusException: INTERNAL: http2 exception;
  nested exception is io.grpc.StatusException: INTERNAL: http2 exception",
  "stacktrace":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception;
  nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.path.MyConsumer.consume(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String, byte[]>,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment)' threw exception;
  nested exception is io.grpc.StatusException: INTERNAL: http2 exception; nested exception is io.grpc.S tatusException: INTERNAL: http2 exception
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:208)
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleRemaining(DefaultErrorHandler.java:135)
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2707)
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2588)
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2457)
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2335)
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2006)
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1375)
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1366)
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1257)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
...
  Suppressed: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Restored Stack Trace\tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:363)
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92)
  at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53
  tat org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2670)
  Caused by: io.grpc.StatusException: INTERNAL: http2 exception
  at io.grpc.Status.asException(Status.java:548)
  at io.grpc.kotlin.ClientCalls$rpcImpl$1$1$1.onClose(ClientCalls.kt:300)
  at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.grpc.v1_6.TracingClientInterceptor$TracingClientCall$TracingClientCallListener.onClose(TracingClientInterceptor.java:161)
  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:564)
  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$100(ClientCallImpl.java:72)
  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:729)
  at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:710)
  at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
  at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  ... 1 more
  Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f
  at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.connectionError(Http2Exception.java:109)



io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.grpc.v1_6.TracingClientInterceptor$TracingClientCall$TracingClientCallListener.onClose(TracingClientInterceptor.java:161). Looks like OpenTelemetry does that gRPC call. Nothing to do with Apache Kafka by itself. It is that tracing instrumentation you have around your Kafka Consumer.
